# Implementing a "generic" mechanism to handle temporal data in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, temporal

I'm trying to accomplish a "generic" mechanism for updating temporal data in my SQL Server database, using Entity Framework.

What I did is create a "marker" interface called `ITemporalData` that defines two properties that need to be present - `DateTime ValidFrom` and `DateTime? ValidTo`.

```
public interface ITemporalData
{
    DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    DateTime? ValidTo { get; set; }
}
```

I was hoping to implement a "generic" approach in my `DbContext.SaveChanges()` override to:

- clone any `ITemporalData` object, which would give me a new object to store (`EntityState.Added`), and set its `ValidFrom` value to the current date&time
- reset the original, modified entry to its database values (calling `.Reset()` on the entity) and then setting the `ValidTo` for that "old" record to the current date&time

While I can easily filter out the modified `ITemporalData` objects in the `SaveChanges()` override like this:

```
public partial class MyDbContext
{
    // override the "SaveChanges" method
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;

        // get the modified entities that implement the ITemporalData interface
        IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry<ITemporalData>> temporalEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<ITemporalData>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified);

        foreach (var temporalEntity in temporalEntities)
        {
            // how would I do that, really? I only have an interface - can't clone an interface...... 
            var cloned = temporalEntity.Entity.Clone();

            // and once it's cloned, I would need to add the new record to the correct DbSet<T> to store it

            // set the "old" records "ValidTo" property to the current date&time
            temporalEntity.Entity.ValidTo = currentDateTime;
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I'm struggling with the "clone the modified record" approach - I only have a `ITemporalData` interface, really - but the cloning (using AutoMapper or other approaches) always depends on the *actual*, underlying concrete datatype.....

Comment: What exactly is the problem with cloning? You can create new instance via reflection and copy propeties from your temporalEntity (again via reflection) to it, not?

Comment: @Evk: OK, so if that works (not entirely convinced yet...) - how do I add that new instance to the *correct* `DbSet` in my context? How can I find that out?

Comment: could you use a db trigger? i used those for automatic versioning.

Comment: @DanielA.White: I possibly could - but I was hoping to solve this at the Entity Framework level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clone entity you might just create new instance via reflection (`Activator.CreateInstance`) and copy all primitive (non-navigation) properties to it via reflection. Better not use auto-mapper tools for that, since they will access navigation properties too, which might cause lazy-loading (or at least ensure lazy-loading is disabled).

If you don't like reflection (note that auto-mappers will use it anyway) - you can also inherit your interface from `ICloneable` and implement `Clone` method for every `ITemporalData` entity (if your entities are autogenerated - use partial class for that). Then each entity decides itself how to clone, without any reflection. This way also has benefits in case your clone logic is complex (for example involves cloning related objects from navigation properties).

To add entity to correct DbSet, use untyped [Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method of `DbContext`:

```
this.Set(temporalEntity.GetType()).Add(temporalEntity);
```

Comment: This looks very promising - thanks for the answer ! I'll investigate a bit further and let you know

Answer (score 1):

You can add this `Clone` method to your context:

```
T Clone<T>(DbEntityEntry<T> entry)
    where T : class
{
    var proxyCreationEnabled = this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled;
    try
    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var clone = (T)entry.CurrentValues.ToObject();
        Set(clone.GetType()).Add(clone);
        return clone;
    }
    finally
    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = proxyCreationEnabled;
    }
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
var cloned = Clone(temporalEntity);
```

`clone.GetType` will return the actual type of the cloned object, whereas `T` will be the compile-time type, `ITemporalData`.

This uses EF's own infrastructure to create a clone, which no doubt is faster than reflection.

Although the clone's state is immediately set to `Added`, it won't perform lazy loading. But it may be safer to ensure that the clone will never be a proxy and, hence, will never trigger lazy loading in case you decide to do other things with a clone. (Thanks Evk for his keen comments).

Comment: Good idea, didn't know about CurrentValues.ToOjbect(). And how this behaves with navigation properties when lazy loading is enabled?

Comment: @Evk. Good question. Only scalar properties are copied by `ToObject`. Navigation properties are not lazy loaded (because the clone is not a proxy). I think this is the desired behavior, otherwise potentially a large object graph would be copied (which is "interesting" if this graph contains other `ITemporalData`s).

Comment: Interesting why clone is of dynamic proxy type then. Navigation properties are indeed not copied and not loaded on cloned object, but it's of DynamicProxy... type.

Comment: I see why - after you attach clone to the context (by adding) - it becomes regular proxy and its navigation properties can be lazy-loaded. So it's not exactly true that clone is not a proxy.

Comment: @Evk You're right. I use a similar clone method in my own code and for that reason I temporarily disable proxy creation (overlooked it here). In this case, lazy loading doesn't occur because the entity's state is `Added`. It may be safer though to include the same switch here.